# Java Swing Layout these components

Tags: java, swing, layout, user-interface, awt

I want to layout  4 components A, B, C, D in a panel like the following graph.
What layout or methods can I use to do this?

P.S. if placing A and D in parallel is easier, it is acceptable. I just want that D is rightmost and a bit northward, but A,B ,C are vertically centered in the middle.

A B C are supposed to be aligned. I feel sorry about my bad drawing.

[image]

Comment: Are the left and right edges of A, B, and C not aligned on purpose?

Comment: For `GridBagLayout` set the constraints' anchor to `FIRST_LINE_END` and fill to `HORIZONTAL` to get D where you want it.  (I can post example if you need.)

Comment: You can also try layered layouts, JLayeredPane and JDesktopPane where you don't use .add but also you have to setBounds giving x, y, width, height of your component, this will NOT naturally resize your components automagically, you would have to write your own size behaviors.

Comment: @Smitty please post an example. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. Like others have mentioned, `GridBagLayout` Is one of the most popular and powerful layout managers in native Java. You could also use `GroupLayout`, which I like better, but which is harder for some to wrap their heads around...but if you're not opposed to adding a 3rd party library, I'm using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) for most everything these days. Layout constraints are strings, and everything's relatively straightforward to put together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example.  This will make sure that the D component is always in the top right, and the A, B, C components are always in the center.  Run it and drag the frame larger.  You'll see the D component will always be in the top right corner of the panel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        frame.add(new MyPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {    
        public MyPanel() {
            JTextField labelA = new JTextField("Your A component");
            JTextField labelB = new JTextField("Your B component");
            JTextField labelC = new JTextField("Your C component");
            JTextField labelD = new JTextField("Top Right D");

            JPanel north = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            north.add(labelD, gbc);

            JPanel south = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            south.add(labelA, gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            south.add(labelB, gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            south.add(labelC, gbc);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(south, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```